# how to make two fragments communicate each other inside viewpager in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

Suppose, I have two fragments , FragmentA and FragmentB inside viewpager .When i click the button in fragmentA then it should be able to add the textview in another fragmentB.so, how is it possible ....please help me out.

```
class Myadpter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    Fragment fragment =null;
    public Myadpter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position==0){
            fragment = new Post();
        }
        if(position==1){
            fragment = new ActiveChat();
        }
        if(position==2){
            fragment = new LastUsers();
        }
        if(position==3){
            fragment = new Noname();
        }

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using broadcast receiver @Shures

Answer (score 1):

Implement a interface to communicate between two fragments, the class where the view pager is will be a middle man

Comment: thanks everyone for your respond...i solved it by using parentFragment and childFragment combination

Answer (score 0):

As already stated by the other user, implementing an interface is the way to go. This link [Communicating with Other Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) will explain in more detail how to achieve what you are attempting to do. Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do as follows:

**Fragment A**

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

OnButtonPressed mCallback;
Button yourButton;
TextView textViewFragA;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    yourButton = findViewById(R.id.yourBtn);
    textViewFragA = findViewById(R.id.textViewFragA);

    yourButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.yourBtn:
            mCallback.onButtonPressed(textViewFragA);
            break;
}

 @Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        mCallback = (OnButtonPressed) getActivity();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(getActivity().toString()
                + " must implement OnButtonPressed");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    mCallback = null; // Avoid memory leaking
    super.onDetach();
}

/**
 * Interface called whenever the user has clicked on the Button
 * @param textView The TextView to add in FragmentB
 */
public interface OnButtonPressed{
    void onButtonPressed(TextView textView);
}
}
```

**FragmentB**

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment{

TextView textViewFragB;

 @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
}

 @Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    textViewFragB= findViewById(R.id.textViewFragB);

}

public TextView getTextViewFragB(){

return textViewFragB;
}
```

**Activity**

```
public class TabControllerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentA.OnButtonPressed{

MyAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_layout);

// Your Stuff

}

// Everytime the user clicks on the Button in FragmentA, this interface method gets triggered
@Override
public void onButtonPressed(TextView textViewFragA) {

FragmentB fragmentB = (FragmentB) adapter.getItem(1)/* Be careful here and get the right fragment, 

otherwise the App will crash*/

// Since you got the TextView and not only the text inside of it,
// you can do whatever you want. Here for example we set the text like the textViewFragA. 
//In a few words you turn the textViewFragB to the other one
fragmentB.getTextViewFragB().setText(textViewFragA.getText().toString());

}

}
```

Hope it will help